# Clickable contents to places with if/else statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a code where the first part is an empty list and the second part is with 8 numerical buttons, I want people to click any 6 numbers randomly and I want the 6 clicked numbers to show up in the above empty list, I can make them clickable and even send them to the empty list but I can't seem to code the part where if I have already clicked a random number, the second random number would either replace the first number or wouldn't show at all, I want the numbers to be listed as they are randomly selected. I hope y'all understood my problem, Thanks for helping. <3

I used javascript, and its working flawless, I tired the if-else statements, for eg (not going into detail) when x is clicked I want it to go on the first place (this works) "if this place already obtained by y, I want the x to go down"(

I expect the randomly clicked buttons to list as they are randomly clicked.

(I'm new here, sorry if I couldn't help much)

EDIT: The Code

```
<head>

    <title>Choose 6 Numbers</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        .border {

        padding:0;
        border:none;
        background:none;
        background-color:none;
        outline:none;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <p>You picked:</p>  

        <ul>

            <li id="placeOne"></li>
            <li id="placeTwo"></li>
            <li id="placeThree"></li>
            <li id="placeFour"></li>
            <li id="placeFive"></li>
            <li id="placeSix"></li>

        </ul>   

    <p>Pick 6 random numbers:</p>

        <ul>



            <li><button id="two" class="border">2</button></li>
            <li><button id="three" class="border">3</button></li>
            <li><button id="one" class="border">1</button></li>
            <li><button id="seven" class="border">7</button></li>
            <li><button id="six" class="border">6</button></li>
            <li><button id="nine" class="border">9</button></li>
            <li><button id="eight" class="border">8</button></li>
            <li><button id="four" class="border">4</button></li>
            <li><button id="zero" class="border">0</button></li>
            <li><button id="five" class="border">5</button></li>

        </ul>

        <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Reset</button>
        <button>Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("two").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "2";

        }

        document.getElementById("three").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "3";

        }

        document.getElementById("one").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "1";

        }

        document.getElementById("seven").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "7";

        }

        document.getElementById("six").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "6";

        }

        document.getElementById("nine").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "9";

        }

        document.getElementById("eight").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "8";

        }

        document.getElementById("four").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "4";

        }

        document.getElementById("zero").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "0";

        }

        document.getElementById("five").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("placeOne").innerHTML = "5";

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please provide your code for us.

Comment: "*i have a code*". Please add the code to your question. We can't possibly know what's wrong with your code without seeing it.

Comment: Hi, I added the code, thanks for answering, please refer the code and help me.

Comment: Not quite clear on the desired behavior.  What do you want to happen if one of the "places" in the first list has a number assigned when the user clicks on one of the items below ?  There are a few possibilities altogether.  1.  At first, list item is empty, just populate with number.  2.  List item is assigned.  If the user clicks on one below that will populate that item, do you want it overwritten, left alone, etc.  3.  Do you want to "stop" when they are all populated, etc.  Maybe explain a little more.

Comment: As it is now, you always just put the clicked number into placeOne ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <title>Choose 6 Numbers</title>

 <style type="text/css">

    .border {

    padding:0;
    border:none;
    background:none;
    background-color:none;
    outline:none;

    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<p>You picked:</p>  

    <ul>

        <li id="place1"></li>
        <li id="place2"></li>
        <li id="place3"></li>
        <li id="place4"></li>
        <li id="place5"></li>
        <li id="place6"></li>

    </ul>   

<p>Pick 6 random numbers:</p>

    <ul >
        <li><button id="two" class="border">2</button></li>
        <li><button id="three" class="border">3</button></li>
        <li><button id="one" class="border">1</button></li>
        <li><button id="seven" class="border">7</button></li>
        <li><button id="six" class="border">6</button></li>
        <li><button id="nine" class="border">9</button></li>
        <li><button id="eight" class="border">8</button></li>
        <li><button id="four" class="border">4</button></li>
        <li><button id="zero" class="border">0</button></li>
        <li><button id="five" class="border">5</button></li>

    </ul>

    <button onClick="window.location.reload(true);">Reset</button>
    <button>Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 let i=1;
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("border");
for (var j = 0; j< classname.length; j++) {
classname[j].addEventListener('click',function() {
var attribute = this.innerHTML;
if(i<7)
{
     document.getElementById("place"+i).innerHTML = attribute;
     i++;
 }
alert(attribute);
})
} 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I replaced the document.getelement and replaced it with one getclass to 
    grab all the similar buttons. Track the adding with i and put it in the 
    list.